# How to get single data from collection

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using vue3 and firestore

Referring to the firestore official document, there was a way to get documents through collection. But this is the way to get all the collection data.

```
const citiesRef = db.collection('cities');
const snapshot = await citiesRef.get();
snapshot.forEach(doc => {
  console.log(doc.id, '=>', doc.data());
});
```

I want to get a single document through collection.

How to get a single documemt is

```
const cityRef = db.collection('cities').doc('SF');
const doc = await cityRef.get();
```

This is a collection followed by a doc().

I can't insert a value in the doc because documemt is an auto-generated ID.
So I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 1):

You have not mentioned the which document you are specifically looking for. In case you don't know the ID of the Firestore Document, you can try running a [simple query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#simple_queries) using `.where()` like this:

```
const db = firebase.firestore()
db.collection("cities").where("cityName", "==", 'London').get().then(querySnapshot => {
  const matchedDoc = querySnapshot.doc[0]
})
```

The example above finds the document where the field `cityName` is equal to `London` (both case sensitive). [QuerySnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot) contains all the documents which matched your condition specified in the where() method. But in case you know there is only one matching document, as in my case I only have one doc with cityName as London, you can directly access the doc data this way: `querySnashots.docs[0].data()`. `querySnapshot.docs` is an array. `[0]` is the first document in it and `.data()` parses data from the doc. Additionally you can use `querySnapshot.size` to get count of documents returned from the query.